# Does json.dump() in python rewrite or append a JSON file

Tags: python, json

When working with `json.dump()` I noticed that it appears to be rewriting the entire document. Is this correct, and is there another way to append to the dictionary like `.append()` deos with lists?

When I write the function like this and change the key value (name), it would appear that the item is being appended.

```
filename = "infohere.json"
name = "Bob"
numbers = 20

#Write to JSON
def writejson(name = name, numbers = numbers):
    with open(filename, "r") as info:
        xdict = json.load(info)
    
    xdict[name] = numbers

    with open(filename, "w") as info:
        json.dump(xdict, info)
```

When you write it out like this however, you can see that the code clearly writes over the entire dictionary/json file.

```
filename = infohere.json
dict = {"Bob":23, "Mark":50}
dict2 = {Ricky":40}

#Write to JSON
def writejson2(dict):
    with open(filehere, "w") as info:
        json.dump(dict, info)

writejson(dict)
writejson(dict2)
```

In the second example it only ever shows up the last date input leading me to believe that this is rewriting the entire document. If the case is that it writes the whole document during each `json.dump`, does this cause issues with larger json file, if so is there another method like .append() but for dealing with json.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... Just add data to the dictionary before you write it again? What is the actual difficulty here?

Comment: When I change the name and numbers variables, via user input, I want it to add to the current dictionary in the json file not rewrite the entire document.

Comment: You cannot "add to a JSON file". JSON is the representation of a single data structure. If you want to modify parts of it, you load the file, change the data, and write the whole thing back to file. That's how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Tomalack That's what I wanted to know.  Does this cause issues with large amounts of data?

Comment: At some point this becomes inefficient, yes. If you want something that works like a database, use a database.

Comment: Perfect thank you, could you post that as an answer so I can accept. Or should I delete the question? May be rather low level?

Comment: `json.dump` itself doesn't do either thing, it just writes to the output file at the current position, whatever that current position is. *How you opened the file for write* determines whether it's rewritten from the start (truncated and position at the beginning with `'w'`) or appended to (no truncation and position at the end with `'a'`). However, the result of appending to a JSON file is not valid JSON.

Comment: (By contrast, there are variants like JSONL that _can_ be subject to appends).

Comment: But the point I'm trying to make above is that the premise of the question -- that `json.dump` exercises any control of where in the file your output goes -- is itself incorrect. You absolutely can use it in such a way at to append to other content, or replace content partway through; the result of doing those things is just unlikely to be a file with meaningful and useful content unless you went out of your way to do it cautiously and constrain your inputs and outputs appropriately.

Comment: I will look up JSONL, the user inputs will be severely restricted as it will be a barcode scanner. The barcode will be used as the key, and the value will be returned as either a value or list of values. Its my first project to work on basics that I've learned so far. and then populated into label widgets in a tkinter gui. You could update enter the information and view it all after. Hope that makes sense.

I figured it's adaptable as a POS system, Inventory Management, or something to that effect for future projects.

Comment: Using a real database is something to prioritize learning if you're looking to build that category of software. They're not just faster (which they are when used correctly), a good one will also be more robust against data loss if your program crashes at the wrong time; and because they can do indexed searches, they make it a lot easier to operate on data that won't all fit in memory at once. That doesn't need to mean installing a separate daemon -- look at how SQLite is built into modern browsers for things like cookie management, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Neither.

`json.dump` doesn't decide whether to delete prior content when it writes to a file. That decision happens when you run `open(filehere, "w")`; *that* is what deletes old content.

## But: Normal JSON isn't amenable to appends.

A single JSON document is one object. There are variants on the format that allow multiple documents in one file, the most common of which is JSONL (which has one JSON document per line). Unless you're using such a format, trying to append JSON to a non-empty file usually won't result in something that can be successfully parsed.

Comment: That makes sense now sorry for the terminology error in the question. When writing a JSON Object it's all one unit, I can import to python as a dict or string, modify and "dump" it back in the json file. When the truncation is at the end (changed ```open(filehere, "w")``` to ```open(filehere, "a")``` ) it created a new object (line) but it would have to be a JSON lines file in order to work with it and using the JSON lines library.